# varios clientes en java sockets

Tags: java

hola me gustaría que en mi servidor pudiesen conectarse varios cliente a la vez

```
package server.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server {

  public static void run(){

    int puerto = 9000;    
    BufferedReader entrada;
    DataOutputStream salida;
    Socket socket;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

 try{

       serverSocket = new ServerSocket(puerto);
       socket = serverSocket.accept();
       String thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
   System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp);
       while( true){

       }


   }catch(IOException e){};
 }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Para ello tienes que crear una lista de sockets donde guardar cada una de las conexiones. Ademas también tienes que preparar tu codigo para escuchar varias veces.

```
ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList();
try{
   while( true)
   {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(puerto);
     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     sockets.add(socket);
     String thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
     System.out.println("IP:"+thisIp);
   }


}catch(IOException e){};
```

Si no me equivoco, el proceso se queda bloqueado en el `serverSocket.accept()` hasta que llega una conexión. Si mi creencia es incorrecta, añade un nullcheck antes de añadir el socket al listado.

Comment: No se puede escuchar varias veces sobre el mismo puerto. Este código solo escuchará el primer cliente y luego se irá por el IOException.